# args.Length prints incorrectly from cmd.exe when last character in argument is a \"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-10, args

Create a Console Application with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.  Write one line of code under the Main method.  Call the program from the command prompt.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
```

Call the program with two arguments.  In Windows 10, it prints 1.

```
"C:\Users\MacGyver\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ArgsProblem\ArgsProblem\bin\Debug\ArgsProblem.exe" "C:\" a2
```

### EDIT:

Turns out the length becomes 1 if the first parameter is inside quotes and the last character in the string is a `\`.  This is causing the length of args to be 1.  Why would this be?  I realize that a `\"` means a quote in a C# string, but in order to make a console application intuitive, it's better to fix the bug inside your code, instead of forcing the end user to remember to put an extra `\` before `\"` to properly escape a backslash in a command line utility.

Broken (args.Length = 1):

```
"C:\Users\MacGyver\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ArgsProblem\ArgsProblem\bin\Debug\ArgsProblem.exe" "C:\" a2
```

Not Broken (args.Length = 2):

```
"C:\Users\MacGyver\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ArgsProblem\ArgsProblem\bin\Debug\ArgsProblem.exe" "C:" a2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing simple Windows command line behaviour. The `\` is saying that the double quotes does not end the string (ie the argument). Try running a program to show exactly how the arguments are handled. On my Windows 10 computer I tried this program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} arguments", args.Length);
    int argIndex = 0;
    foreach (string ss in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0,3}:  '{1}'", argIndex, ss);
        argIndex++;
    }
}
```

it gave these outputs. Note that the `\` escapes the double quote, but it is not part of the resultant string.

```
C:\>showarguments ab c
There are 2 arguments
      0:  'ab'
      1:  'c'

C:\>showarguments "C:\" a2
There are 1 arguments
      0:  'C:" a2'

C:\>showarguments "C:" a2
There are 2 arguments
      0:  'C:'
      1:  'a2'
```

Comment: So I guess in order to solve it the way I want (to not force the end user to understand escape sequences), I have to parse the single argument by its spaces, and then replace any quotes with a "\" character for any of the split strings.  BUT, only if there is a double quote character in the first argument, otherwise use normal logic for multiple arguments.  It's a hack, but I guess that'll work.

Comment: Finally works.  What a hack job, but it's pretty on the outside!  :-)